# How to integrate custom api (cURL call) into WordPress child theme

Tags: wordpress, curl, wordpress-rest-api, php-curl

How can I integrate third-party API to wordpress theme. Is there any pre-build wordpress function for cURL calls?

Here is code with the parameters:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => {{API_URL}},
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "host: {{API_HOST}}"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
```

Comment: Can you offer more context.  What exactly are you trying to do with the data?

Comment: For issuing HTTP requests from within Wordpress, check out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/